# How to use VFMA instructions in armv7 (Cortex A5) iOS?

Tags: ios, assembly, arm, fpu

I want to use VFMA instruction in my project. However, the assembler will report an error as instruction requires VFP4.

Comment: So what CPU and FPU options are you giving the assembler?

Comment: Something is wrong in the question...Apple never used Cortex-A5 in iDevices

Comment: @MaratDukhan Could be a case of confusion with the Apple A5 SoC, in which case the answer to the question would be "you don't", since the Cortex-A9s in that only do VFPv3.

Comment: I am using apple 32-bit ipad in that they are mentioned that it has dual core A5 processor so i thought A5 means cortex A5. If my assumption is wrong please give me which processor they are using.

Comment: @ravi ARM processor naming is FUBAR. Here are the architectures for Apple's SoC: A4 = ARM Cortex-A8 core, A5 = ARM Cortex-A9 core, A6 = Apple Swift core, Apple Cyclone core, Apple Typhoon core. Cortex-A8 and Cortex-A9 **do not** support fused multiply-add instructions. If you use VFMA
 for other reasons than extended accuracy, VMLA instruction would probably suit your needs.

Comment: Thanks for your information.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable the FPU in the compiler/assembler options. The GCC option is `-mfpu=<name>`. The possible values for this option are listed [on this page](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/ARM-Options.html). You probably want to use something like `-mfpu=vfpv4` or `-mfpu=neon-vfpv4`. Your IDE probably have a field for this compiler option; mine is under "Architecture->Floating point". <strike>You may also need to enable the FPU in software on the chip at startup. Consult the ARM documentation for this.</strike> (**EDIT** : Since you said iOS, it is certainly already enabled)